# PySpark reassign values of duplicate rows

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, duplicates, python-3.7

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id,p1
1,A
2,null
3,B
4,null
4,null
2,C
```

Using PySpark, I want to remove all the duplicates. However, if there is a duplicate in which the p1 column is not null I want to remove the null one. For example, I want to remove the first occurrence of id 2 and either of id 4. Right now I am splitting the dataframe into two dataframes as such:

```
id,p1
1,A
3,B
2,C
```

```
id,p1
2,null
4,null
4,null
```

Removing the duplicates from both, then adding the ones which are not in the first dataframe back. Like that I get this dataframe.

```
id,p1
1,A
3,B
4,null
2,C
```

This is what I have so far:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
d = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1,"A"),
     (2,None),
     (3,"B"),
     (4,None),
     (4,None),
     (2,"C")],
    ["id", "p"]
    )
d1 = d.filter(d.p.isNull())
d2 = d.filter(d.p.isNotNull())
d1 = d1.dropDuplicates()
d2 = d2.dropDuplicates()
d3 = d1.join(d2, "id", 'left_anti')
d4 = d2.unionByName(d3)
```

Is there a more beautiful way of doing this? It really feels redundant like this but I can't come up with a better way. I tried using groupby but couldn't achieve it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(df1.sort(col('p1').desc())#sort column descending and will put nulls low in list
 
.dropDuplicates(subset = ['id']).show()#Drop duplicates on column id
)

+---+----+
| id|  p1|
+---+----+
|  1|   A|
|  2|   C|
|  3|   B|
|  4|null|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use window **`row_number()`** function and **sort** by **`"p"`** column `descending`.

**`Example:`**

```
d.show()
#+---+----+
#| id|   p|
#+---+----+
#|  1|   A|
#|  2|null|
#|  3|   B|
#|  4|null|
#|  4|null|
#|  2|   C|
#+---+----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window_spec=row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("p").desc()))

d.withColumn("rn",window_spec).filter(col("rn")==1).drop("rn").show()
#+---+----+
#| id|   p|
#+---+----+
#|  1|   A|
#|  3|   B|
#|  2|   C|
#|  4|null|
#+---+----+
```

Comment: I get `'Column' object is not callable`. But will definitely follow up on learning how to use row_number and Window. Thanks!

Comment: @mnsr, make sure you are closing all brackets, I was able to execute above code without any issues!

Comment: Actually, you are right! My bad. Thank you very much.